# How to Create a Global Calendar in Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

How can we make a calendar global in Google Apps?  I want the calendar to appear in the "My Calendars" box when I type the name of the calendar.

So far what I have done is to create the calendar and share it with the members of the Google Apps domain, but I can't figure out how to find the calendar in another user's calendar setup.  I don't want to share the link to individuals - I want the calendar to be available to everyone by default.

[Google has a description](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083?hl=en) of how to make a calendar `Public`, but that kind of public means the calendar is available to the entire world, not just your Google Apps domain users.